# Groovy Optional parameter omit center value

Tags: methods, groovy, parameters

I have a method in groovy. This method has second parameter as param?. I want to omit this parameter and pass only first and third parameter. Is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Not without changing your class

Why not add a new method that only takes 2 parameters?

Or move the optional parameter to the end and give it a default value?

Or you could define a method that returns a closure that only takes 2 params (and sticks a default value in for the middle parameter)

```
String threeParams(String a, int b, String c) {
    "$a:$b:$c"
}

Closure midCurry(int b) {
    { String a, String c -> threeParams(a, b, c) }
}

def twoParams = midCurry(1)

assert twoParams('tim', 'yates') == 'tim:1:yates'
```

Comment: You are talking about the method overloading but as groovy give the default value option in parameter. Can I leave the middle for default and rest of them I provide myself.

Comment: No. I don't think. Not 100% sure I understand though